Is it true that $(D Q D)^+ = D^{-1} Q^+ D^{-1}$?
Let $Q$ be a real, symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, and $D$ a strictly positive diagonal matrix. Is it true that
$$
(D Q D)^+ = D^{-1} Q^+ D^{-1}?
$$
Of course this is true in the scalar case and in the case that $D = I$.

The answer is no, this is not generally true. As a counterexample, consider the matrices
$$
D = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 2}, \quad Q = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$
Note that $Q = Q^+$. We compute
$$
D^{-1}Q^+D^{-1} = D^{-1}QD^{-1} = \frac 18 \pmatrix{4 & 2\\2 & 1}.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
[DQD]^+ = \pmatrix{1/2 & 1\\
1 & 2}^+ = \frac 2{25}\pmatrix{1 & 2\\2 & 4}.
$$

Note that your matrix $M = D^{-1}Q^+D^{-1}$ fails to satisfy all the conditions that define the MP pseudoinverse. For instance, we find that the matrix $AM$ fails to be symmetric since
$$
AM = (DQD)(D^{-1}Q^+D^{-1}) = DQQ^+D^{-1} \\
= DQD^{-1} = \frac 14 \pmatrix{2 & 1\\ 4 & 2}.
$$
$MA$ similarly fails to be symmetric.
